# How to delete rounded edges of ToolBar without control template?

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I try to do it next way:

```
    <ToolBar x:Name="toolBar" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button BorderBrush="Black" Content="READ" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

        <ToolBar.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ToolBarMainPanelBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </ToolBar.Resources>
    </ToolBar>
```

It doesn't work. I don't want to change style of whole ToolBar using template. How to do it?

Comment: How do you expect a named resource to work without an explicit assignment?

Comment: I expect decision in xaml or code behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by putting your `Toolbar` inside the `ToolBarTray` as follow,

```
  <ToolBarTray>
            <ToolBar x:Name="toolBar" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button BorderBrush="Black" Content="READ" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

        <ToolBar.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ToolBarMainPanelBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </ToolBar.Resources>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: Welcome! @SQLprog

Comment: It is adding 'edgy' borders to the button instead of changing the rounded border of the toolbar, so I'm amazed that this solves the question.

Comment: You can offer your decision. I'll consider that.